# Laptop can connect to an external Minecraft 1.12.2 server on same internet, but desktop can't

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am attempting to connect to a new server in Minecraft known as **Geographica**. It is a **bukkit 1.12.2** server. I tried connecting to this on my desktop last night, but I couldn't so in order to troubleshoot, I tried connecting on my laptop and it worked fine. Both using the same internet and the same ip for the server.

**Attempting to Connect on Desktop**

[image]

**Error after Attempt**

*io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception:connection refused: no further information:*

[image]

**Troubleshooting on Desktop**

- Restarted Minecraft
- Reinstalled Minecraft (Twice, Full Uninstall, Deleted .minecraft folder)
- Turned off Firewall completely after restarting my computer
- Attempted to remove any firewall restrictions regarding connection to servers

As you can assume, none of these work. Obviously, this is a client-side issue since I was able to connect on my laptop with the same Minecraft account.

Anyway, hopefully, someone will be able to help me out here! I feel like my testing has narrowed the possibilities of what is wrong down quite a bit. But then again, there is a chance for there to be way more issues. Thanks guys!

Comment: 1. Try waiting ~10s before clicking on the server. 2. Try reinstalling Minecraft on your laptop, to make sure they really both have the same configuration. Of course make a backup of what you need before. 3. Try a new .minecraft folder on both devices. 4. Does the same happen with any other server? 5. Try getting a new IP address. Usually this works by just disconnecting and reconnecting to the internet, but sometimes it doesn't. Check wieistmeineip.de to make sure.

Comment: Hey! I appreciate the response, but I'm pretty certain it is none of those.

1. I've done that multiple times. 
2. I did that on the laptop too since it wasn't downloaded before. 
3. I have completely uninstalled minecraft by deleting that folder. 
4. It has never happened with any server. 
5. That shouldn't be the issue if I can connect on my laptop.

Comment: 3. Deleting that folder does not uninstall Minecraft, it just deletes some of your saved data. 5. It could, your IP might be blocked on the server and it might send a weird response instead of the usual "you're blocked".

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes that is completely uninstalling Minecraft. Of course, I uninstall it from the Windows 10 App area, but I thought that in order to completely uninstall it, the .minecraft folder had to be deleted.

Comment: @FabianRöling if they were IP blocked, the laptop's connection would also be refused since it's all on the same network. most IPs are static now, and don't change PC to PC.

Comment: @EarthToAccess I was thinking the same thing, thanks for the response. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You can't have the same (public) IP on both computers, otherwise they could both not access the internet.

Comment: eh, that's true, but then by that logic wouldn't that defeat the purpose of an IP ban? if i can just grab my account (which in this instance, would work since only one *client* is failing, not the account), move to another computer, and be perfectly fine, then something isn't right-- but that's not the case with most IP bans, it somehow finds all instances of someone on that network (regardless of the account used)

Comment: Figured I would just ping this since I have yet to get an answer that works!

Comment: @Fabian Röling: Home routers use Network Address Translation. Your (ISP facing) router is given an 'external' IP by your ISP that all your devices share when talking to the internet. Each device in your home network has a unique IP address that is not visible to the internet.  Your router knows what devices are on your network and 'translates' the internal addresses to the ISP assigned address, but also appends a unique port number for each device (for outgoing packets). When packets come back in, the router reverses this process so the packet gets routed to the correct device in your network.